# PHP 7.4.3 Strpos is not working on server but locally

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to solve a problem right now. Namely, I am writing an application that asks for the customer's privacy consent. For this I have created a database that stores the values.

To check if the customer has already consented to an item, I write the consents to a string, which I call result. If the string contains a certain value, then a "delete button" is displayed. If the customer has not yet agreed, then a consent button should be inserted.

Locally (PHP version 8) I have already coded everything. Here it also works as desired.

On the server (PHP version 7) I first used str_contains. However, I found out that this only works from PHP version 8. So I tried it with strpos, stristr and other methods. Unfortunately the check never takes place correctly on the server. Locally it works with strpos, stristr, etc.

```
<?php include "../functions/notLoggedIn.php"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <!-- Eigenes CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    <!-- Titel der Webseite -->
    <title>Datenschutzeinwilligung</title>
    <!-- Favicon Icon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigationsleiste -->
    <?php include_once "nav_logedin.php"?>
    <!-- Seiteninhalt -->
    <div class="container x-height-app">
        <h1 class="text-center mt-3">Datenschutzeinwilligung</h1>
        <?php 
            /* Alle aktuellen Datenschutzeinwilligungen des Kunden selektieren */
            include "mysql.php";
            $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM privacy, privacy_user WHERE privacy.PRIVACY_ID = privacy_user.PRIVACY_ID AND USER_ID = '" . $_SESSION['USER_ID'] . "' AND privacy_user.VALID_TILL IS NULL;");
            $stmt->execute();
            $users = $stmt->fetchAll();
            foreach($users as $user){
                $result .= "".$user['PRIVACY_ID']."";
                echo $result;
            }
            /* Funktion, welche ausgeführt wird, wenn der 'update'-Button geklickt wird */
            if(isset($_POST['update'])){
                $PRIVACY = $_POST['privacy'];
                $USER_ID = $_SESSION['USER_ID'];
                $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO privacy_user SET USER_ID=:USER_ID, PRIVACY_ID=:PRIVACY_ID, VALID_FROM=now()";
                $pdoQuery_run = $mysql->prepare($pdoQuery);
                $pdoQuery_exec = $pdoQuery_run->execute(array(":USER_ID"=>$USER_ID, ":PRIVACY_ID"=>$PRIVACY));
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
            }
            /* Funktion, welche ausgeführt wird, wenn der 'delete'-Button geklickt wird */
            if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                $PRIVACY = $_POST['privacy'];
                $USER_ID = $_SESSION['USER_ID'];
                $pdoQuery = "UPDATE privacy_user SET `VALID_TILL`=now() WHERE USER_ID=:USER_ID AND PRIVACY_ID=:PRIVACY_ID AND VALID_TILL IS NULL";
                $pdoQuery_run = $mysql->prepare($pdoQuery);
                $pdoQuery_exec = $pdoQuery_run->execute(array(":USER_ID"=>$USER_ID, ":PRIVACY_ID"=>$PRIVACY));
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
            }
        ?>
        <!-- Verarbeitung personenbezogener Daten -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <div>
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="card shadow pb-2 bg-body rounded">
                        <h3 class="text-center card-header">Verarbeitung personenbezogener Daten</h3>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <input type="hidden" id="" value="1" name="privacy">
                            <?php
                                echo (stristr($result, 1) !== false)?'<button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" type="submit">Ich willige nicht ein</button>':'<button class="btn btn-primary" name="update" type="submit">Ich willige ein</button>';
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        ....
        ... here are more checks like the above shown
        ....

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <?php include_once "footer.php"?>
</body>

</html>
```

Do you have any idea what I can improve in the code? If there are any questions about the code, just ask.

I'm grateful for any tips. Have a nice day!

Greetings Max

Comment: Did you try `strpos($result, '1') !== false`?

Comment: I do not know why I have not tried this. Thanks a lot, now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `strpos($result, '1') !== false`?